# Kinect v2 calibration and depth color mapping

Tags: image-processing, 3d, kinect, point-cloud-library, camera-calibration

I calibrated my kinect v2 using GML C++ Camera Calibration Toolbox and I got the following result:

```
=== View Transform ===
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
=== Projection Transform ===
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
=== Intrinsic ===
988.639062 0.000000 952.817637
0.000000 990.207877 590.581358
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
=== Distortion ===
0.027207 -0.029469 0.011052 0.000348 
=== Position ===
0.0 0.0 0.0
=== Extrinsic ===
0.160906  -0.701212  0.694558  -535.166867
-0.986880  -0.123795  0.103646  -143.419070
0.013305  -0.702123  -0.711932  543.277485
0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

Now the intrinsics look good (similar to other calibration results I found on the internet) but the extrinsics look really weird. Others look almost like the identity matrix.

[image]

If I just use the translation vector and the rotation matrix the point cloud looks good, but the colormapping is wrong as well because the body is shifted. I'm showing a picture of the body with all blue pixels because the color mapping doesn't work yet.

I'm following those approaches:
http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration

http://developers-club.com/posts/272629/

Am I missing a step ?

Is there any normalisation of the calibration needed ?

Maybe because of the different resolutions of depth and RGB?